# Determining the constant of acceleration in a circular motion

Tags: circles, constants

The acceleration towards the centre of a star is proportional to $x^{-2}$ where $x$ is the distance from the centre. That is, $\ddot{x}=-\frac{k}{x^2}$.

A satellite is orbiting a star with a constant speed, $V$, at a fixed distance $R$ from the centre of the star. Its period of revolution is $T$. If it moves in a uniform circular motion show that $k=\frac{4{\pi}^2R^3}{T^2}$.

I'm confused on how to determine the acceleration. I know that I can get the answer by squaring the speed of rotation, which is $\frac{2\pi}{T}$ and then multiplying it by $-R$ then subbing that into the equation when $x=R$ but I don't understand how squaring the speed of revolution nor multiply it by $-R$ would give the acceleration. Am I on the right train of thought or is it just a coincidence that I can get the answer this way?

Comment: You already have an answer that confirms that it is **not** a mere coincidence that your calculation matches the answer--or at least it would do so if you understood the notation. It might help people giving answers to know what tools you have available to you.

Answer (score 1):

For constant revolution in a circle the velocity is given by the following equation

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}
$$

By differentiating once w.r.t. time we get the acceleration equation

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}\vec{r}&=\vec{\omega}\times\left(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}\right)+\left(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\omega}\right)\times\vec{r}\\
\\
&= \vec{\omega}\times\left(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}\right)+0\\
\\
&=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry I'm unfamiliar with this notion, what does $\overrightarrow{r}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ mean?

Comment: @Quippy they are the position and angular velocity vector respectively

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you write it using $v$ as velocity and $x$ as displacement, I'm confused as to does $\overrightarrow{r}=x$ in this case?